# Getting error while using http in node.js

Tags: node.js

Below is the error getting while calling http get request

```
events.js:66
throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:123:16)
```

PFB my code throwing the error

```
var options = {
host: 'http://xyz.com',
port: 80,
path : 'test?query=' + escape(req.params.searchTerm) + '&offset=0&hits=500',
method: 'GET',
headers: {
Cookie : "session=" + session
}
};

console.log("Start");
var x = http.request(options,function(subRes){
console.log("Connected");
subRes.on('data',function(data){
console.log("===================data===" +util.inspect(data));
});
});

x.end();
```

Any ideas, why this error ?

Answer (score 3):

`ENOENT` is an error that indications name resolution did not return any results. You specify the hostname as `http://xyz.com`, but colons are not allowed in hostnames. You want:

```
var options = {
    host: 'xyz.com',
```

Answer (score 2):

You specify the host as `http://xyz.com`, which should just be `xyz.com`.

This value is used to resolve the IP address of the host you're trying to connect to using DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Now I am getting a different error

events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1263:15)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1314:23)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:356:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)